# firefox snap: typo in configure hook prevents instalation

Tags: firefox, snap

Just upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04. This happens when installing firefox:

`(run hook "configure": cannot perform operation: mount --rbind /dev /tmp/snap.rootfs_1CHZkB//dev: No such file or directory)`

The second instance of the word /dev should be separated with a space from the previous word. Where to find the code for the configure hook?

Comment: Is the upgrade otherwise complete?

Comment: That error prevents firefox from upgrading. It keeps showing on apt upgrade.